# mysql query slow down when using group by and order by in a same query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm a beginner to mysql. I have to fetch the most viewed contentid(for the past 120 hours) from the table views. The views table contains 200,000 (lakh) records. I have indexed the contentid column, but my query takes upto 10 sec to fetch the result.

Views table structure is as follows:

```
contentid viewed                ip
155     2011-10-26 00:07:52     216.251.77.226
1150    2011-10-26 00:08:15     65.52.109.72
1134    2011-10-26 00:08:30     178.53.54.221
14      2011-10-26 00:08:49     178.53.54.221
693     2011-10-26 00:08:58     115.184.174.136
433     2011-10-26 00:09:14     66.249.71.138
558     2011-10-26 00:09:26     91.83.214.3
715     2011-10-26 00:16:01     128.171.36.161
226     2011-10-26 00:16:06     110.36.39.102
562     2011-10-26 00:16:51     84.3.173.188
1134    2011-10-26 00:16:53     110.39.67.139
198     2011-10-26 00:16:57     220.227.133.163
155     2011-10-27 05:43:59     64.135.215.142
155     2011-10-27 08:39:46     157.55.39.86
155     2011-10-27 11:23:05     99.55.166.146
155     2011-10-27 15:40:29     174.255.241.202
1150    2011-10-26 00:50:50     119.30.96.83
1150    2011-10-26 01:02:58     66.249.71.138
1150    2011-10-26 08:02:31     95.144.197.55
1132    2011-10-26 00:16:07     119.160.126.99
```

and my query is

```
SELECT contentid FROM views 
where viewed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 HOUR) 
GROUP BY contentid ORDER BY count(contentid ) desc limit 0, 15
```

Comment: Try running `EXPLAIN` `$your_query`; You could also check this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: Just a guess here, perhaps date_sub is taking lots of time computing each value, instead you could try to add a new field which contains the seconds since the unix epoch, for example time() in php, and then change the where to new_field > 120 * 3600 for 120 hours.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? What does the EXPLAIN show?

Comment: @ypercube : Explain shows - type=range, possible_keys=viewed, key=viewed,key_len=4, ref=null,rows=73440,Extra=Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: So the query is using the `(viewed)` index. Try adding the `(contentid, viewed)` index. I think it will result in faster performance. (No guarantee though, it depends on your table distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that nice indexes for this query would be either a simple index on `viewed` or a compound index on `(contentid, viewed)`.

---

You should also change the `COUNT(contentid)` to `COUNT(*)` :

```
SELECT contentid FROM views 
WHERE viewed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 120 HOUR) 
GROUP BY contentid 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Comment: Thank you ypercube. Indexing to the viewed column speeds up the query execution.

Answer (score -1):

I have an understanding , and this might be wrong, that `Now()` function will be called for every row, Why not call this function once and save the result and use the result in the query.

Try adding an Index on `viewed`  column, this way the mysql might not have to go to table. All data required for execution of this query will be available in in index files.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have tried what you said. But it doesn't make any big difference.

Comment: @nithi please see one more suggestion.